# Keep getting this kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel, kernel-panic

I keep getting this kernel panic once a week and a half roughly. It freezes the computer (2010ish 17" MBP), showing this error:

[image: (i'll upload the photo soon)]

And giving this error dump on reboot:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  888565 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    08D63BEE-8C75-4526-B019-3656DE3F605C

Fri Mar  2 15:38:12 2012
panic(cpu 1 caller 0x226ec0): "thread_invoke: preemption_level -1, possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:1471
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x4c5fbe18 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x4c5fbe4c 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x4c5fbe68 : 0x226ec0 (0x593ab8 0xffffffff 0x593a50 0x226790) 
0x4c5fbee8 : 0x2275c6 (0x14cb87c4 0x0 0x44a00000 0x1) 
0x4c5fbf58 : 0x227631 (0x23014c 0x863ea0 0x0 0x2a45c9) 
0x4c5fbf78 : 0x2302e6 (0x23014c 0x863ea0 0x0 0x0) 
0x4c5fbfc8 : 0x2a179c (0x863ea0 0x0 0x10 0x9416164) 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBookPro5,2 (Mac-F2268EC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 910038174880710
unloaded kexts:
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard  7.1 (addr 0x1ac2000, size 0x40960) - last unloaded 839800501350443
loaded kexts:
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftMouseUSB  7.1 - last loaded 841989895086801
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftMouse 7.1
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboardUSB   7.1
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard  7.1
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   3.1.2
com.vmware.kext.vmioplug    3.1.2
com.vmware.kext.vmci    3.1.2
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   3.1.2
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 9.7.1
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.3d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.20
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.31
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.57
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.0.5f14
com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU  1.5.2d10
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    76
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.GeForce   6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   2.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  303.8
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  1.6.4
com.apple.BootCache 31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   428.42.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   160.0.0
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  1
com.apple.security.quarantine   0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   142.6.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  76
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    6.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    76
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   76
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    76
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   76
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    76
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  76
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.0d5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.0a1
com.apple.NVDAResman    6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 207.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   1.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   2.6.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   320.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.2.4
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  6
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 289
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0
Model: MacBookPro5,2, BootROM MBP52.008E.B05, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 3.06 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.42f4
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256A, 233.76 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS21N
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver V1.0, 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation), 0x071d, 0x06200000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8217, 0x06110000 / 4
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0236, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Think it could be caused by my MS keyboard, like these guys? http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=861155

Comment: Had the same kernel panic with my 2010 17" MBP. Had to have the motherboard replaced. Another similar case here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/macbook-pro-15-mid-2010-crashes-upon-waking-up-from-sleep-sometimes/35384#35384

Comment: I'd highly recommend running the Apple included Hardware Test Tool to see if it finds anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find out, if the kernel panic is caused by hardware failure or software/driver related conflicts!

The best way is always to get an idea of what might causing the problem in the first place, therefore you need to gather information and closely observe your system, processes, behavior etc.. in order to pinpoint back to the problem. Secondly, try to recreate the problem, just to make sure your suspicion is correct. The last step is finding the solution to your problem.

This line of information suggest, that `MicrosoftKeyboard` kext (kernel extension) is causing the panic!!

```
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard  7.1 (addr 0x1ac2000, size 0x40960) - last unloaded 839800501350443
```

**You can try the following:**
Download a [linux live cd](http://livecdlist.com/) and boot into it, with no external devices attached, like keyboard, mouse, hdd etc.. if you don't encounter any problems when trying to recreate your problem / or in  due time, boot back in your os x partition (with no external devices attached). - (This step only makes sense, if you have no idea of what might be the problem whatsoever!)

Kill all system processes related to "MicrosoftKeyboard" and relocate the `com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard.kext` which can be found here `System/Library/Extensions` to another dir, so it will not be loaded when you reboot your OS.

That is my best guess!! Please report back for results.

---

**Edit:** You are welcome Chris and hopefully it resolves the kernel panic issue!!

Comment: I think you're right about the keyboard. I've done some googling and it looks like it's a common problem that MS's lousy intellipoint drivers cause kernel panics. I'll refund the keyboard. Thanks!